# Simple method to find p-Value

Tags: statistics, filemaker, chi-squared, p-value

I'm not a mathematical, please be gentle...

I'm looking for a simple method to find the p-value corresponding
to a give chi-squared (one degree of freedom).
I want to put this into a computer program (FileMaker); accuracy is not important.

From this discussion: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5830281

i have extract 3 formulas:

---

First formula:

p(x)=a/x^3 + b/x^2 + c/x + d

where x = chi-squared and a, b, c and d are constants.

range from 0,1 to 3, then:
a 0.00350853 / b -0.0623318 / c 0.357489 / d -0.0049905

range from 3 to 12, then:
a -3.1258 / b +2.81657 / c -0.387984 / d 0.0152614

---

Second formula:

You can use the relationship between chi-squared with one df and the
standard normal, as given by others, and then approximate the standard
normal. There are different ways to do this: I went digging in
Abramowitz and Stegun and found this:

P(x)=Prob(X <= x) approx = 1-0.5(1+c_1 x+c_2 x^2+c_3 x^3+ c_4
x_4)^(-4)

(the whole bracket raised to power -4),

where 
c_1=0,196854 / c_2=0,115194 / c_3=0,000344 / c_4=0,019527

with an error claimed to be less than 2.5 x 10^{-4}.

---

Third formula:

1/(1 + Exp[-.496937z*Sqrt[z^2 + 10.28]])

---

i tested, but the result are not good... but i'm sure that in the linked discussion the expression are correct (it's my "translation" that is wrong).
Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the first two formulas didn't pan out; I didn't examine them.

The third formula turns out to work, but you accidentally copied the wrong formula from the discussion.  In that post they mention your formula for the normal distribution but *this* formula for the chi^2 approximation:

```
2/(1 + Exp[.496937*Sqrt[x(x + 10.28)])
```

I coded that into python and compared to `scipy.stats.chi2.cdf`.

```
In [7]: def f(z):
   ...:     return 2.0 / (1.0 + math.exp(0.496937*math.sqrt(z*(z+10.28))))
In [10]: def g(z):
   ...:     return 1.0 - stats.chi2.cdf(z,1)
In [14]: values = [ (f(x), g(x), abs(f(x)-g(x))) for x in range(1,10) ]
In [15]: values
Out[15]:
[(0.317115565250687, 0.31731050786291415, 0.0001949426122271336),
 (0.1570262524187356, 0.15729920705028488, 0.000272954631549277),
 (0.08324399687489754, 0.08326451666355039, 2.051978865284798e-05),
 (0.0456977583763344, 0.04550026389635853, 0.000197494479975871),
 (0.02564668451495894, 0.02534731867746831, 0.0002993658374906283),
 (0.014616925322419972, 0.014305878435429631, 0.00031104688699034114),
 (0.008425622375436589, 0.008150971593502754, 0.00027465078193383494),
 (0.004898868275754985, 0.004677734981047288, 0.0002211332947076967),
 (0.0028675732116189585, 0.002699796063260207, 0.00016777714835875153)]
```

So your error (the third value in each row) is coming in around 3*10^-4.  Looks pretty good...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the formula is corret for all ChiSquare with 1 degree of freedom. Now the problem is to find the formula for 2 or more degree of freedom, because this formula didn't work...

Comment: Hmm...now you're changing the specifications of the problem!  The approximations on that thread were specifically for the case of 1 d.f.  This [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2348373?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) has an approximation which is designed for higher degrees of freedom.  I tested it and it seems to work pretty well for d.f.>=10 but definitely doesn't work well for low d.f.  So you probably need to find several different approximations for different regimes.  (or find a stats library like `scipy` for your programming language)